# Is there a size limit of SQLite database on Android?

Tags: android

I want to store .db file internally in device sdcard and want to access the data from it.
Can some one tell the maximum size of the .db file can be retrieved in our android application with out any memory exceptions.

Answer (score -4):

The maximum size of SQLite is : 10MB to 30 MB and it depends on Android internal memory.

Comment: "The maximum size of SQLite is : 10MB to 30 MB and it depends on Android internal memory." ... it depends what you mean by "SQLite" ... 1. if you think about Cursor ... then yes ... but 2. if you think about  database file size ... than you're wrong ... 3. or i'm wrong so please, could you put link to resources where is stated that db file limit is 10-30MB ...