# Android and inflating a 40mb SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an SQLite database which is 40mb uncompressed. It will only be read.

I can condense and split this database into a few text files, each less than 1mb, bundle these into an apk, and generate the database with this say by running a script on the device the first time my app is run.

Are there any restrictions on the size of the resulting generated SQLite database if it goes to external storage?

Vague question - if there are no such restrictions, is this likely to be done in a "short" time on "most" devices?

Answer (score 0):

Belong what is said in this topic : [Is there a size limit of SQLite database on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330103/is-there-a-size-limit-of-sqlite-database-on-android)

It seems to be 10 to 30 mb for your database.

But, you should find more information about SQLite limits by following this link : 
http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html